# What romanization system is this? （"sin thai juan" for "心太軟")

Tags: romanization

I came across [this music video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7mZCPMWKII) which features a pretty weird romanization system, I don't think I have seen before and I couldn't find any information on it (it is not listed on the list of romanization systems on Wikipedia). Any idea on what it is?

Comment: Looks like a 闽南-台湾 system. Haven't seen it before.

Comment: It isn't Wade-Giles, though having some elements of it. It's most likely an arbitrary system invented by the transcriber of the karaoki video.

Comment: What is "romanization system", the word not in the dictionary. The song was sung by a Taiwanese singer.

Comment: See also: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/38585/22079. IMO it's just an ad-hoc Malay-based romanisation system.

Comment: @r13 罗马化. See dictionary.com and possibly wikipedia.

Comment: @mika Thanks. I typed in "romanization", Dictionary.com returned the word (verb) "romanize". Looks like someone has made up the word, romanization, perceivably a noun.

Comment: @r13 Same results here, dictionary.com attaches the Romanization and Romanizer to Romanize, in the "Related forms" section (I am using an offline cache fetched in 2016, maybe changes were made)

Comment: It seems combine several systems: 
心太软
通用拼音 Sin Tai Ruan
威妥瑪拼音 Hsin T'ai Juan
Result searched from: http://pank.org/pinyin/

Answer (score 1):

It's Hokkien Pinyin in Southeastern Asia. See Wikipedia for 东南亚福建话拼音.